# How to disable laravel logs temporarily?

Tags: logging, laravel, monolog

I felt into a log recursion problem and I would like to disable logs only for a single operation. Is there any kind of runtime switch for Laravel logs? Like:

```
<?php
Log::stop();
// bypass log here
Log::resume();
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that through the facade like on example above. What's the best way to turn Laravel log off temporarily?

Comment: There is no such a way unless you manually make it off.

Comment: What's the best way to turn it off temporarily?

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do would be to fix the log recursion problem - why do you get runaway recursion? Are you logging something with a circular reference and it tries to resolve it? If so, maybe the best way is to override the `__toString` or `jsonSerialize` (or whatever) method so that the circular reference is not included in the object when it's being converted to something loggable.

Comment: @alexrussell I'm logging to database, but database call from log listener function is being logged... and then recursion happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hacky way to do it. Swap the facade instance with a mock.

With [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery):

```
$app = Log::getFacadeRoot();
Log::shouldReceive('error', 'warning', 'debug', 'info', 'notice', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency');

// bypass log here

Log::swap($app);
```

Without Mockery:

```
class LogMock {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {}
}

$app = Log::getFacadeRoot();
Log::swap(new LogMock);

// bypass log here

Log::swap($app);
```

Comment: That is so dirty. I love it! Actually the use of `Facade::swap` looks ideal for this. Didn't realise it existed.

Comment: I found another way, but this is indeed a great idea! :)

Comment: I'll mark this one as the preferable solution because it's very general and works for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible (less general) solution in case you are registering custom listeners is to use `Config` facade to store state and bypass a given callback:

```
<?php

Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time, $name){
    if(Config::get('log.enabled', true)){
        Log::info($query, ['context' => ['bindings' => $bindings]]);
    }
});

Log::listen(function($level, $message, $context) {
    Config::set('log.enabled', false);
    // do something bypassing listener who expects log.enabled 
    Config::set('log.enabled', true);
});
```